# java.net.SocketException: Socket closed not caught by RxJava onError (Single)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am doing something like this: in my `Fragment`, I am observing a `LiveData` exposed by a `ViewModel` that encapsulates different UI states like error, loading, success state, etc. Within the said `ViewModel`, I start an RxJava2 stream that kicks off a chain of REST API requests via Retrofit:

```
    public LiveData<UIState> doSomething() {
        compositeDisposable.add(somethingRepo.doA()
            .andThen(somethingRepo.doB())
            .andThen(somethingRepo.doC())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> status.setValue(UIState.LOADING()))
            .subscribe(() -> status.setValue(UIState.SUCCESS()), error -> {
                Log.d("SettingsVM", "error: " + error.getClass().getSimpleName());

                if(error instanceof VersionAlreadyExistsException) {
                    status.setValue(UIState.VERSION_EXISTS());
                } else {
                    status.setValue(UIState.ERROR(error.getMessage()));
                }
            })
        );
        return status;
    }
```

However, according to my custom logger that implements `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger`, I am getting a `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` during `somethingRepo.doA()`, but it seems that I am not getting the Exception in `doSomething()`'s `onError`. Here is the full `somethingRepo.doA()`:

```
public Completable doA() {
    return api.doRequest(paramRepository.getUrl(false),
        paramRepository.getAuthorization(),
        paramRepository.getName())
        .flatMapCompletable(requestResponse-> {
            if(paramRepository.getVersion().contentEquals(requestResponse.getVersion())) {
                return Completable.error(new VersionAlreadyExistsException());
            } else {
                return Completable.complete();
            }
        });
}
```

api.doRequest is a `GET` request that looks like this:

```
@GET
Single<RequestResponse> doRequest (
        @Url String url,
        @Header("authorization") String authorization,
        @Query("merch") String name);
```

Interestingly, on another Android app, I sent a `POST` to the same URL I am using in the previous example and what I got was `HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /180.232.98.122:7443`.

I am aware of a similar [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2708) being opened in the official Retrofit repo and a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324941/socketexception-unsubscribing-request-without-onerror), but those two are unresolved, thus I would like to hear if anyone here has encountered the same behavior.

Comment: did you check internet connectivity ? Have declared internet permission ?

Comment: did you check apis on postman or any api client?

Comment: have you declared usesCleartextTraffic in manifest?

Comment: @Quicklearner I have the necessary permissions and a working internet connection. Also, sorry, the answer you linked to is not relevant to my question.

Comment: did you check the api on postman client or any other ?

Comment: @Quicklearner Did you even read my question? If you really understand my question you would realize that my problem would not be resolved via a simple Postman check.

Comment: @Quicklearner Before any more irrelevant comments appear, please note that this error isn't caused by internet connectivity or lack of permissions. It is caused by *this application* closing the socket and then continuing to use it. It indicates a bug in the code somewhere.

Comment: Do you have a StackTrace? Could you please post it, if possible. Is api#doRequest lazy or eager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Firstly, I implemented an "inactivity timer" that returns all screens (I use `Fragments` for screens) to the first/home screen in my app. So let's say a value of 30 seconds was set to the timer, if no interaction with the UI happens and the timer reaches 30 secs then my app goes back to the home screen.

Secondly, the `ViewModel` where I kick off the requests is tied to a `Fragment` since it implements `DefaultLifecycleObserver`, which means that it will receive `LifecycleOwner` changes/callbacks, provided I call this: `getViewLifecycleOwner().getLifecycle().addObserver(viewModel)` in my `Fragment#onViewCreated`. I then override `onStop(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner)` in the `ViewModel` and call `compositeDisposable.clear()`, which means I want to sort of cancel all pending API request I made using RxJava2 once the `Fragment` my `ViewModel` is tied to receives `onStop`.

The final piece of info is that the timeout value for my `OkHttp` client is greater than the inactivity timer value, so the inactivity timer abruptly causes my request API to be cancelled even before it finishes.

To summarize, here is what happens: when the inactivity timer is up, the request API `Fragment`'s `onStop` is called as the screen changes back to the home screen, and then the `ViewModel` calls `compositeDisposable.clear()` which disposes the current RxJava disposable, thus I am unable to receive anything on `onError`.